# Pairwise Welch’s Test for unequal variances and results generalization

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I am looking for any suggestions regarding the direction of statistical analysis in the following problem.

**Problem:**

Let us assume $N$ independent subjects. At each subject I observe a variable let say $X$ that depends on two factors, i.e. $Y \in \left\{ Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_K \right\}$ and $Z \in \left\{ Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_L \right\}$. These factors are fixed in the experiment. In other words, for each subject out of  $N$, I get $K L$ separate groups of experimental data sets, each of them presenting the realizations of the variable $X$ under different fixed parameters ($Y_k$, $Z_l$). The group sizes across a selected subject remain the same; however, they are different across the subjects. Moreover, the variances across different groups for a selected subject and different subjects might be different.

**What I want to do:**

- To evaluate the differences in sample means between the groups $(Y_1, Z_1)$ and $(Y_k, Z_l)$ for $k, l \neq 1$ (a pairwise comparison) for each subject individually, and then provide some general information/conclusion about all the subjects. In other words, I want to generalize the results obtained for each subject separately to the group of $N$ subjects.
- To evaluate the correlation between the groups $(Y_1, Z_1)$ and $(Y_k, Z_l)$ for $k, l \neq 1$ for each subject individually, and then provide some general information/conclusion about all the subjects.

**A preliminary work:**

- I have applied the Welch’s Test for unequal variances and checked if the sample means between the groups $(Y_1, Z_1)$ and $(Y_k, Z_l)$ for $k, l \neq 1$ are significantly different. However, I have no idea how to generalize the results to the group of $N$ subjects?

Maybe other ideas on evaluating the statistical properties of the data adequately except for the pairwise Welch’s Test for unequal variances?
Thank you.

Comment: There are generalization of Welch's t-test or Satterwaithe correction in the case of one-way or two-way ANOVA, e.g., B. L. Welch (1951), On the comparison of several mean values: an  alternative approach,  _Biometrika_, *38*, 330-336a; Howell, D. C. (2013), _Statistical Methods for Psychology_, Belmont, CA: Wadsworth Cengage Learning.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the direction.